# Python generator creates duplicates of yield results when appended to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield

My generator function "returns" / yields what I want (when printed), but if I append the results to a big list, many duplicates of the yields are in the list. Why? How can I avoid this?

**Input:**

```
input = [
[
    {'orgunit': '013107','attr1': 2, 'attr2': 3},
    {'orgunit': '013113','attr1': 20, 'attr3': 30},
],
    [{...}]
]
```

Where the `dict`s of the input share common `orgunit`s.
If I print `isolated`:

**Goal** (but appended each element to a list):

```
>>> print isolated
{'dataElement': 'attr1', 'value': '2', 'orgunit': 013107}
{'dataElement': 'attr2', 'value': '3', 'orgunit': 013107}
{'dataElement': 'attr1', 'value': '20', 'orgunit': 013113}    
{'dataElement': 'attr3', 'value': '30', 'orgunit': 013113}
```

**Methods and generator:**

```
def transform(input):
    values = []
    gen = process_event(input)
    for event in gen:
        values.append(event)
    # print
    print values

def process_event(input):
    for i in xrange(len(input)):
        for event in input[i]:
            isolated = {}
            isolated['orgunit'] = event['orgunit']
            for key, value in event.copy().iteritems():
                isolated['dataElement'] = key
                isolated['value'] = value
                # print
                print isolated
                yield isolated
```

**What I get instead:**

```
>>>print values
    {
        "dataElement": "attr1", 
        "value": 2, 
        "orgunit": "013107"
    }, 
    {
        "dataElement": "attr1", 
        "value": 2, 
        "orgunit": "013107"
    }...
```

Comment: Seems you modify the same dictionary, so items returned by the first and second yield are the same in meaning of references. Simple solution is to create new isolated dictionary inside the deeper FOR, not outside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you modify the same dictionary, so items returned by the first and second yield are the same in meaning of references. Simple solution is to create new isolated dictionary inside the deeper FOR, not outside of it.

So the correct version of your code is:

```
def process_event(input):
    for events_list in input:  # It's more pythonic way to iterate over items, not by indices
        for event in events_list:
            orgunit = event['orgunit'] # Save current orgunit
            del event['orgunit'] # You will get "dataElement: orgunit" without this. Also you can make a copy and delete from a copy to do not corrupt input list
            for key, value in event.iteritems(): # You do not need copy here
                isolated = {'orgunit': orgunit} # The main point - each time create new isolated dict
                isolated['dataElement'] = key
                isolated['value'] = value
                # print
                print isolated
                yield isolated
```

And the output:

```
>>>input = [[
    {'orgunit': '013107','attr1': 2, 'attr2': 3},
    {'orgunit': '013113','attr1': 20, 'attr3': 30},   ]]    
>>>transform(input)


{'dataElement': 'attr1', 'value': 2, 'orgunit': '013107'}
{'dataElement': 'attr2', 'value': 3, 'orgunit': '013107'}
{'dataElement': 'attr1', 'value': 20, 'orgunit': '013113'}
{'dataElement': 'attr3', 'value': 30, 'orgunit': '013113'}
```